# How can I make an overloaded constructor for an actionscript 3 class?

Tags: actionscript-3

How can I override a class constructor in as3?

```
public class Cargar{

public Cargar(){
}

public Cargar(sobrecargado:object){
}
}
```

Comment: All questions are [expected to be in English](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/). Please improve your question by editing it and changing to English.

Comment: I can't suggest an edit for this question for some reason, but the title and topic translate to "How can I make an overloaded constructor for an actionscript 3 class?"

Answer (score 5):

`Actionscript 3.0` does not support overloading of functions. As `constuctor` is a function too, so you can't overload it.But you can do something like this:

```
public class Cargar{
    public Cargar(sobrecargado:Object=null):void{
         if(sobrecargado === null){
             initByEmptyObject();
         }else{
             initByObject(sobrecargado);
         }
    }
    //surrogate of `Cargar()` constructor
    private function initByEmptyObject():void{

    }
    //surrogate of `Cargar(sobrecargado:object)` constructor
    private function initByObject():void{

    }
}
```